# How to create double relationship Room

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have to create this relationship in room, but i don't know how to do it.

I created all the tables, but i don't know how to create the double relation between "notification" and "user_access_to_company"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like in `user_access_to_company` table you have **composite primary key** (i.e. primary key consists of more than one field).

As for `notification` table, it looks like it includes a **composite foreign key**.

Room library supports both types of composite keys:

```
@Entity(primaryKeys = ["firstName", "lastName"]) // <-- Composite primary key
data class UserAccessToCompany(
    val user_idUser: Int,
    val company_idcompany: Int
)

@Entity(foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
    entity = UserAccessToCompany::class, 
    parentColumns = arrayOf("user_idUser", "company_idcompany"), 
    childColumns = arrayOf("user_access_to_company_idUser", "user_access_to_company_idcompany"))
]) // <-- Composite primary key
data class Notification(
    @PrimaryKey val idNotification: Int,
    // ...............
    val user_access_to_company_idUser: Int,
    val user_access_to_company_idcompany: Int
)
```